# No type inference with DataRowCollection

Tags: c#, datatable, type-inference, datarow, datarowcollection

I have a project that stores some data from SQL in a `DataTable` and then maps each `DataRow` to a custom class instance.

When I loop *over* the `Rows` property (which is of type `DataRowCollection`), there's no type inference.

So this doesn't work:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Int32.Parse(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
    // doesn't compile
}
```

But this does:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Int32.Parse(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
}
```

Why can't the compiler figure out of what type the `row` is? Could the `var` keyword stand for something else in the case of enumerating over a `DataRowCollection`? Is there something else, besides data rows, that could be enumerated over in a `DataRowCollection`?

Is that why you would need to be explicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `DataRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`(via [`InternalDataCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)) but not the generic, typed `IEnumerable<T>`. The class is simply too old.

By specifying the type in the `foreach` you're casting it implicitely.